# Calculating consumption is returning zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a query to calculate the consumption (delta) of values in a table.

I have tested this on numerous data sets and the value returned is always zero.

Here is a DB fiddle with the dataset and query:
[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1b8d21268827bb526f019eaf8eec7a83)

The first row in the dataset is the starting point and will be zero. The second row in the results table should be 0.2 and so on.

I can't work out why zero is coming back, I am clearly doing this entirely wrong.

The expected output would look like:

```
2209    27/09/2018 22:45:00 0.00    v1
2209    27/09/2018 23:00:00 0.01    v1
2209    27/09/2018 23:15:00 0.03    v1
2209    27/09/2018 23:30:00 0.02    v1
2209    27/09/2018 23:45:00 0.02    v1
2209    28/09/2018 00:00:00 0.02    v1
2209    28/09/2018 00:15:00 0.02    v1
2209    28/09/2018 00:30:00 0.00    v1
2209    28/09/2018 00:45:00 0.05    v1
2209    28/09/2018 01:00:00 0.02    v1
```

An important point is where a row is zero, the value will be zero. But the consumption in the next row will be less the value before the zero. This is shown in row 8 and 9.

TIA

Comment: Can you explain your logic. Your expression for `CountConsumption` is `MAX(CAST(ChannelValue AS NUMERIC(10,2))) - MIN(ChannelValue) `, however, `ChannelValue` is `int`. An `int` minus an `int` can **never** evaluate to a `decimal`, so the value `0.2` would be impossible for that expression. Expected results and a description of them would greatly help here.

Comment: You forgot to include the explanation.

Comment: The fiddle added those. I have changed the fiddle to represent how the table actually is. Sometimes the channel value can be text (for other channels, not the one used in this case). I do filter these out in another query.

Comment: Also, again, `ChannelValue`, is a **`int`**. It can't store decimal values. the value `8924.2`will be stored as `8924`.

Comment: @Larnu The idea is that I move through the data two rows at a time, taking one from the other. In terms of the int thing, I have removed that from the fiddle, as the fiddle created the data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements in the question are a bit unclear, but the sample data and comments do clarify them.

Basically you need `lag()`, but you also want to ignore `0` values.  There is not a trivial way to accomplish this in SQL Server.  The standard has `IGNORE NULL`s, but that is not implemented.

One method would be a cumulative max.  However, that would require that the data always be increasing.  Although that might be the case, this is not explicitly mentioned.

All that said, the following returns your specified results:

```
SELECT SerialNumber, ChannelName, ReadingDate AS [DateConsumption],
       ChannelValue - LAG(ChannelValue, 1, ChannelValue) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber, ChannelName ORDER BY ReadingDate)
FROM UriData
WHERE ChannelValue <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT SerialNumber, ChannelName, ReadingDate AS [DateConsumption], 0
FROM UriData
WHERE ChannelValue = 0
ORDER BY SerialNumber, ChannelName, DateConsumption;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d565c8c3632cffc692e7ccfe35abc207) is a db<>fiddle.

Some additional notes:

- There is no reason to convert a `datetime` column to a `datetime`.
- I changed `value` so it is a numeric rather than a string.  Store data using the appropriate types.
- I recommend storing missing data as `NULL` rather than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your datatype of `ChannelValue` to a `decimal` (perhaps a `decimal(10,2)`) this gives you most of the results you're after:

```
SELECT UD.SerialNumber,
       UD.ReadingDate,
       ChannelValue - LAG(ChannelValue,1,ChannelValue) OVER (PARTITION BY ChannelName ORDER BY ReadingDate ASC)
FROM UriData UD;
```

It goes "wrong" when `ChannelValue` goes to `0`, but again, we are missing the logic behind your requirements. Hopefully this gets you the distance

*Edit: This guess seems to do it:*

```
SELECT UD.SerialNumber,
       UD.ReadingDate,
       ChannelValue - LAG(ChannelValue,1,ChannelValue) OVER (PARTITION BY ChannelName, CASE ChannelValue WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY ReadingDate ASC)
FROM UriData UD
ORDER BY ReadingDate;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=00f800869ec08a25b36a0a3e91dbd6bd)

Comment: Where a row is zero, the value needs to remain at zero. But the consumption in the next row will be less the value before the zero. This is shown in row 8 and 9.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin what I guessed. Why explanations are important.

Comment: Added a db<>fiddle for you too @TheOrangeGoblin which seems to get the correct results.

Comment: I always struggle with SQL case and forget about LEAD and LAG. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @TheOrangeGoblin. If it works, please do mark it as the solution so that future readers know that the answer helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping (among other columns) on `ReadingDate`. This means every group will consist of one row.  Within that group, `max(ChannelValue)` will be the same as `min(ChannelValue)`. Subtracting two equal values results in zero.